# Possiblt to bridge a HTTP file GET to a multi-part file POST?

Tags: http, post, get, multipart

I'm not sure if this is possible, but:

I have a server A that will accept files via a multi-part POST.
I have a server B from which files can be obtained via a GET request.

While obviously, I can transfer a file by downloading from B, then uploading to A,
is there any way I can somehow 'bridge' the requests, such that I can transfer a file
from B to A, without it having to pass through a third machine i.e. B uploads directly to A.

Comment: There is technically nothing that prevents this, you just have to code it.

Comment: @bgp Can you expand on that? The important part is that *my* computer, or any theoretical third-machine, would be a weak-link if there were any more up/download links than one.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to server A or B's code, then yes, otherwise no.